# Using Ember initializers to set domain related data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a single Ember app that needs to use different data depending on the domain that it's running on. For example, on domain1.com the site title might be "Domain 1 Website", whereas for domain2.org the site title could be "Cool Site!"

I need to be able to use the data in routes, controllers and templates.

My initializer so far:

```js
import { request } from 'ic-ajax';

export function initialize(container, application) {
  var domain = document.location.host;
  return request('http://api/sites?domain=' + domain, {} ).then(function(response) {
    // make the response available to routes, controllers and templates
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'site-data',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the docs:
http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_dependency-injection-with-code-register-inject-code

The second example

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'logger',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var logger = {
      log: function(m) {
        console.log(m);
      }
    };

    application.register('logger:main', logger, { instantiate: false });
    application.inject('route', 'logger', 'logger:main');
  }
});
```

and the following explanation shows you how you can use `.inject` to make one of your variables, services or functions available to whatever objects you need within your application.